# Having trouble understanding lbu instruction

Tags: mips

Im learning MIPS in MARS and i've been trying to comprehend the lbu instruction, I need some help unwrapping concepts.
In the "Help" section, lbu is defined as:

"lbu $t1,-100($t2)"

"Load byte unsigned : Set $t1 to zero-extended 8bit value from effective memory byte address"

1. What does "-100($t2)" do?
2. What does zero-extended 8bit value mean exactly?
3. Am I understanding correctly that the lbu instruction copies the first (rightmost) 8 bits from a register and inserts it to into another register?
4. If so, does the "effective memory byte address" reffer to the origin register (from which the copy is made)?

I can't find any good explanation on this. Perhaps I made my questions a bit convoluted but hopefully you can get the gist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *"lbu $t1,-100($t2)"* `$t1` and `$t2` are placholders for any of the 32 MIPS registers, and `-100` is a placeholder for a 16 bit sign-extended immediate.

The instruction reads a byte from the effective memory address result from adding the contents of the second register (`$t2` in the example) and the 16 bit signed immediate, then the contents of the target register (`$t1` in the example) are loaded with the byte read from memory (in the 8 least significant bits) and filled with 0s in the 24 most significant bits.

So for example you may have the following sample code in MARS:

```
 .data
info: .byte 0x10 
      .byte 0x20
last: .byte 0x30

 .text    
li $a0, 0xFFFFFFFF
la $t0, info
lbu $a0, 0($t0)
la $t1, last
lbu $a1, -1($t1)
li $v0, 10
syscall  # terminate
```

Before executing `lbu $a0, 0($t0)`  `$a0` will hold `0xFFFFFFFF` and `$t0` will hold the address where the data section begins.

After that instruction is executed `$a0` will hold `0x10` that is the content of the first byte of the data section.

Before executing `lbu $a1, -1($t1)`  `$t1` will hold the address where the data section contains the last (third) byte (the address whose contents are `0x30` in the example). Note also that I am using `-1` as the immediate in this instruction.

After that instruction is executed `$a1` will hold `0x20` that is the content of the second byte of the data section.

Comment: Thank you for that very clear example. One more thing, the ```.byte 0x20``` did not have a label, and you did ```-1``` to reach it, is this because data bytes are subsequent of one another, so it doesn't really need one?

Comment: Yes, the `.byte` directive stores them sequentially in memory. The use of a label is just for the assembler to know which address corresponds to that location but is not needed (e.g. in the example shown)

Answer (score 1):

I found a MIPS assembly reference here:

> [https://www.cs.unibo.it/~solmi/teaching/arch_2002-2003/AssemblyLanguageProgDoc.pdf](https://www.cs.unibo.it/%7Esolmi/teaching/arch_2002-2003/AssemblyLanguageProgDoc.pdf)

It says `($t2)` is the address held in register `$t2` (one of the register set `$8` to `$15`), and `-100` means subtract 100 and use that as the actual address.